# MS Access Variable in text field

Tags: ms-access, variables

I want to ask how can I add ID variable to URL adress in my table. Bellow you can see what I mean. Now I have table with columns. First column is an ID and in another column I have URL adress (field is text type). I need to get ID variable to URL address for example like that. [https://website.com/images/[ID]/main.jpg](https://website.com/images/%5BID%5D/main.jpg)

[ID] is a variable what I need to get there.
LINK TO IMAGE: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFMWF.jpg)

Comment: Provide some code to show how you generate it. What is the logic of generating it? The question can't be answered without implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

That will be:

```
=Replace([Mainimageforsolution],"[ID]",[ID])
```

To replace series of [ID]:

```
=Replace("https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/1.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/2.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/3.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/4.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/5.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/[ID]/6.jpg", "[ID]", CStr([ID])
```

Comment: I used that command in UPDATE QUERY and it's working good 
"https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/" & CStr([ID]) & "/main.jpg"

Comment: but now I need to do the same in next columns but there url have to be separated by this mark | for exmaple

http://website.com/images/[ID]/1.jpg|http://website.com/images/[ID]/2.jpg etc... 

how can I do that ? I tried this

"https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/" & CStr([ID]) & "/1.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/" & CStr([ID]) & "/2.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/" & CStr([ID]) & "/3.jpg" & "|" & "https://etiweb.samuelmarcinko.com/images/" & CStr([ID]) & "/4.jpg"

But if I add one more URL  for example 5.jpg it's not working.

Comment: _ it's working good_ - great! Then please mark as answered. As for replacing more that one ID, `Replace` will replace any and all occurences of `[ID]`.

Comment: but how can I solve this problem with 5.jpg and 6 jpg ? if I add only first 4 urls it's working but 5 and 6 url is not working and then my output looks like that: https://imgur.com/a/WbPeZij it ends with 5 and missing .jpg and one more img url 6.jpg

Comment: this is the code full code in UPDATE QUERY / "Update to" field 

https://pastebin.com/F173Uzxp

Comment: And where I can add this replace command ? Sorry I'm new in Access but appreciate your help

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: and where I should put this code ? In SQL view or where ? it's VBA code ? Thanks I'm working 2nd day in Access

Comment: In a query, I guess. Have in mind, please, that we know nothing about your application or the context, apart from the tiny bits you have posted here.

Comment: I uploaded my DB here: https://samuelmarcinko.com/db.zip

Comment: The field _Solutiongallery_ seems to have been updated nicely, so what is your issue, please?

Comment: the problem was that I had set up Solutiongallery field type to short text 255 chars, and urls was not displaying in full format because limit was reached. so it's fixed :)